Keycloak disconnect after refresh page 2024
I have already check and found question/response about my problem, but each time solution is the same. not working for me.
I have a Laravel 10 program with Vue 3 Front-End in the same project.
I use keycloak-js to authenticate my Front-end like this :
const options = {
    clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    realm: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    url: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_URL,
};

let keycloak = new Keycloak(options);
let authenticated;
let store = null;


async function init() {
    const store = useAuthStore();
    try {
        authenticated = await keycloak.init({
            onLoad: "check-sso",
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
        })
        if (authenticated) {
            await initStore(store);
            await setupInterceptors(store);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Keycloak not authenticated")
            await store.clearUserData();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Keycloak init failed")
        console.error(error)
    }
}

I have silent-check-sso.html page in the public folder like that:
my program
Some part are public, so i have a button to connect to keycloak, this part work fine, I can connect correctly.
Could you tell me why my app disconnect? (please)
maybe the problem is here : (I'm in production in Centos8 server) it happen after login page
errors on browser
